Wpf C# разработка с базой данных
хочу разработать WFP приложение на Visual Studio с использованием базы данных. Мне необходим постоянный доступ к базе данных из любой точки мира, по этому решил выбрать в качестве базы данных Гугл таблицу. (Серьёзной структурированной бд в 4 нормальной связи мне не нужно)
Вопрос в следующем: Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает, с чего лучше начать изучение совместной работы WPF и Гугл таблиц, а также как бы это сделать чтобы не получить API ключ в гугле. То чтоб подключаться к таблице по ссылке от лица моего аккаунта к примеру.

С отделения мух от котлет. GUI без разницы откуда берутся данные для отображения, а клиенту гугл таблиц тоже без разницы что с данными будут делать. Одно с другим никак не связано. Начать нужно с поиска клиента гуглтаблиц (Google Sheets) в гугле. Далее пробуете получить сохранить данные и потом уже гуи прикручиваете.

В идеи брать массив данных из столбцов в угле и выводить в комбобокс актуальную информацию по уникальным значениям. Для этого и хочу связать гугл и интерфейс в котором с этими данными уже будут работать. Какие видосы и статьи не смотрю, везде говорят что необходимо сформировать связь. А для этого нужен Апи.


"Таблицы" - это не база. Условный JSON лежащий открыто в GIT и то будет куда удобней с точки зрения разработки, чем "таблицы"... 2. Не хотите использовать специально созданный для разработчиков интерфейс взаимодействия (API) - изобретайте костыли в виде парсинга страницы. Открывайте через HttpClient ссылку, ищите в ней нужные данные, выдирайте эти данные всякими парсерами HTML (если данные в UI), ну и на основе этого получайте свою "базу" без API. 3. Начните с базы... Поймите WPF, поймите его XAML, поймите механизм привязок, почитайте про MVVM, уже потом думайте про свой проект.


Спасибо, идея с JSON действительно очень хорошая. И с парсингом ссылки тоже. Но про "Поймите было конечно обидно". Не судите книгу по обложке....

Я сужу по тому, что вижу. Ну а вижу я сейчас вопрос, который не может возникнуть, будь у автора опыт в программировании. Тут имею ввиду не знание того, как это делать, а простой опыт анализа информации, ее поиск. Ибо будем честны, вы сейчас спрашиваете базовые вещи. Так что не обижайтесь, вы такую "обложку" самостоятельно нам подсунули. Знаете MVVM, умеете делать качественные, структурированные проекты, я буду только рад, ибо меньше будет в будущем на SO базовых вопросов, на которые честно, я уже устал отвечать)
